# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (unable to allocate object)

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I am trying to build iOS application, I get error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PlayerProfileSectionProReviewViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I This error I get when I am trying to execute line `_playerProfileSectionProReviewModel = [[PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel alloc]init];` in method:

```
- (PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel *)playerProfileSectionProReviewModel
{
    if (!_playerProfileSectionProReviewModel)
    {
        _playerProfileSectionProReviewModel = [[PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel alloc]init];
    }

    return _playerProfileSectionProReviewModel;
}
```

Where is the problem? Please help me!

Comment: Check reference for class `PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel` is properly connected with the target.

Comment: View controller has property `@property (nonatomic, strong) PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel *playerProfileSectionProReviewModel;` which is initialized `_playerProfileSectionProReviewModel = [[PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel alloc]init];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your class is reference to target. You can check that by below steps:

Select your class in your case `PlayerProfileSectionProReviewModel` in project navigator. Check utilities window, which is right side property window in Xcode.

And check for **Target Membership** is mark true for current class.

[image]

In above image **Simple** is a project target.